# How to split a download in halves

Tags: c#, file, split, download

I'm creating a program to download files, but I want to only download the first half of a file, and I was wondering if there was any way to do that, preferably in C#.

It is for a download manager that will only download the first half for a file. I also need code to continue the download with the second half (if possible).

Comment: And why would u only like to download 50% of a file ?

Comment: Im making a download manager, just dont ask.... its hard to explain

Answer (score 0):

You can use webrequest and webresponse and check the length with the ContentLength  header field

```
 private void DownloadFile( string  someUrl)
            {

                byte[] result;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

                WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(someUrl);

                using (WebResponse response = wr.GetResponse())
                {
                    long contentLentgth = response.ContentLength;  
                    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (MemoryStream ms  = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            int count = 0;
                            long totalBytes = 0;  
                            do
                            {
                                count = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                                totalBytes = totalBytes + count;  
                                ms.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                                using (FileStream file = new FileStream("file.bin", FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
                                {
                                    byte[] bytes = new byte[ms.Length];
                                    ms.Read(bytes, 0, (int)ms.Length);
                                    file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                                    ms.Close();
                                }
                                if (totalBytes>contentLentgth/2)
                                {
                                    break;  
                                }
                            } while (count != 0);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you might use (via *http* I assume) a stream to receive the body of your http request

[GetResponseStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Code snippet: http://snipplr.com/view/64141/